# How can I describe, in QFT, Weyl spinors coupled to a strong version of the gluon gauge field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, spinors, color-charge

Let's assume a massless Weyl-spinor field. My aim is to let them interact by a gluon-like gauge-field, which has a bigger much bigger coupling, color charge, than the standard color interaction.

This means the spinors don't exist in a free state and we probably have to take refugee for lattice computations to compute, say, a bound state of three or two of them Weyl spinors.

Will the fact that the spinors are massless work in my advantage? Can I transplant the formalism of QCD to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. First of all, what's stopping you to write the Lagrangian of your theory? Second, what do you mean by "gluon-like gauge field with a bigger coupling and color charge"? A $SU(N)$ theory with $N>3$? At which scale would the coupling of your new interaction be bigger than the QCD one?

Comment: @FrodCube Is the Lagrangian same as for quarks interacting by a gluon field but with bigger coupling? I envision three massless particles making up a bound state that has a net "super"color white and a net "normal" color (blue, green, or red).

Comment: You'll need a Yang-Mills Lagrangian, where you will have to decide which gauge group to use. Still saying that the "coupling is bigger" is a bit of a tricky concept, because couplings in general depend on the energy scale, so what's bigger at one energy might be smaller at another.

Comment: @FrodCube I think it's rather strange that the coupling should depend on distance. Isn't this caused by the dressing up of the naked particle which is considered pointlike? What if the particle is not pointlike? Which is another question obviously, but still. If the particle has a Planckian size, we could ignore sub-Planck scales. Thanks for the info, btw!

Comment: Every QFT has running renormalized couplings (unless you have a CFT, but that's not your case). It doesn't matter what's the size of your particles.

Comment: @FrodCube I just don't understand why. Isnt renormalization involved? A new question!